# jquery image slider navigation tabs background image is not changing in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, slider

I am using jquery image slider with 3 tabs having text information in them, in each tab i have given different background images and i want them to change to other image when a tab has hover or active effect, its working well in all the browsers except IE(i have tested in IE7,8,9). In IE when any tab becomes active its background image changes to the active background image of tab3 (last tab). Please let me know if you need additional information.
Below is my html code and its css:

```
<div id="featured_slide">
  <div id="featured_wrap">
   <ul id="featured_tabs">
    <li class="tb1"><a href="#fc1">A<br />
      <span>test message1.</span></a></li>
    <li class="tb2"><a href="#fc2">B<br />
      <span>test message2.</span></a></li>
    <li class="tb3"><a href="#fc3">C<br />
      <span>test message3</span></a></li>        
  </ul>
  <div id="featured_content">
    <div class="featured_box" id="fc1"><img src="images/Main1.png" alt="" />

    </div>
    <div class="featured_box" id="fc2"><img src="images/Main2.png" alt="" />

    </div>
    <div class="featured_box" id="fc3"><img src="images/Main3.png" alt="" />

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

```
  <style>
#featured_slide ul#featured_tabs li.last
{
        border-bottom:none;
}

#featured_slide ul#featured_tabs li.tb1
{
    background:url("../images/Slider1.png") top right no-repeat transparent;
}
#featured_slide ul#featured_tabs li.tb2
{
    background:url("../images/Slider2.png") top right no-repeat transparent;
}
#featured_slide ul#featured_tabs li.tb3
{
    background:url("../images/Slider3.png") top right no-repeat transparent;
}


#featured_slide ul#featured_tabs li.tb1 a:hover
{
    background:url("../images/Slider1Active.png") top right no-repeat transparent;
}
#featured_slide ul#featured_tabs li.tb2 a:hover
{
    background:url("../images/Slider2Active.png") top right no-repeat transparent;
}
#featured_slide ul#featured_tabs li.tb3 a:hover
{
    background:url("../images/Slider3Active.png") top right no-repeat transparent;
}


#featured_slide ul#featured_tabs li.tb1.ui-tabs-selected a
{
    background:url("../images/Slider1Active.png") top right no-repeat transparent;  
}
#featured_slide ul#featured_tabs li.tb2.ui-tabs-selected a
{
    background:url("../images/Slider2Active.png") top right no-repeat transparent;
}
#featured_slide ul#featured_tabs li.tb3.ui-tabs-selected a
{
background:url("../images/Slider3Active.png") top right no-repeat transparent;
}   

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are missing a closing .  add another closing div at the bottom of your html and see if that solves the problem.